# add enter action to animated search form

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using a animated search form based on CSS:

DEMO: https://codepen.io/CBeghin/pen/HeuiF

To open the search bar I have to click on the loupe icon. If I click a second time on the loupe icon, the bar disappears again.Currently I have to press the "Enter"-Key to search for my keyword.

Instead of removing the search bar, while clicking a second time on the loupe icon, I would like to use an enter action to search for my keyword.

I was trying to use javascript, but I don't get the action on the right place:

```
$('input').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
    alert('open search bar');
  } else {
    alert('enter search bar');
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Someone has an idea, how to realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by handling the focus styles via javascript, and moving the magnifying glass in front of the text input once the user clicks it for the first time

```js
$("input[type='text']").focus(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("focus")) {
   $(this).addClass("focus");
    }
  $("input[type='submit']").attr('style', 'z-index: 4');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700);
@import url(https://raw.github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/docs/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css);

body {
 background: #DDD;
 font-size: 15px;
}
#wrap {
  margin: 50px 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 100;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #555;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.795, 0.000, 1.000);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"].focus:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
}

input[type="text"].focus {
  width: 700px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
  cursor: text;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  height: 67px;
  width: 63px;
  display: inline-block;
  color:red;
  float: right;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) center center no-repeat;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <form action="" autocomplete="on">
  <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="What're we looking for ?"><input id="search_submit" value="Rechercher" type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much for helping me.